# Outgoing port 80 blocked on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a Windows 2003 Web Edition SP2 server.

As of now, I am unable to view any website using the browser.

I tried connecting to port 80 on various sites like google.com, yahoo.com using telnet manually, but it doesn't work.

The "Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service is disabled.
There are no policies assigned under IPSEC.
Server provider claims that there is no filtering/blocking being done on their end.

So what is causing this issue and how do I resolve it?

Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ping www.google.com

Pinging www.l.google.com [74.125.235.50] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 74.125.235.50: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=58
Reply from 74.125.235.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=58
Reply from 74.125.235.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=58
Reply from 74.125.235.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=58

Ping statistics for 74.125.235.50:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>


C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>telnet www.google.com 80
Connecting To www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80
: Connect failed

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Comment: Sure that is a issue in the server?
Connect a laptop in the network port to which is connected that server for confirm that.

Comment: This is a dedicated server. I am not at liberty to bring my laptop to connect to it.

Comment: Seems like a Firewall issue.

Comment: At the provider endpoint or the server machine?

I am guessing at the provider endpoint since I have disabled mine totally.

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to browse the Web from a server? That is extremely ill-advised. There is a reason why current versions of Windows Server enable IE "Enhanced Security Configuration" by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot connect outbound to port 80 from this machine, even with telnet, and there is no firewall software running on the local machine, then the issue must reside with a firewall located further upstream in your network.

Are servers on your LAN allowed to connect to external web sites at all?

Comment: You may need to use a proxy server in order to exit the network. Also, disabling your firewall is a bad idea.

Comment: Very good point about checking to see whether a proxy server is required.